# How to "make proxy" of shape keys in blender 2.8

Tags: shape-keys

I have set up a scene file. I have linked a character and have done "make proxy" of rigs. now I need to "make proxy" of the "shape keys" of that character. But it does not work.
Can anyone help me with this? I need to use the shape keys of the linked file.
I am using blender 2.8.

Comment: Do you use a driver on the shape key controlled by an armature bone? Mind to share the file?

Comment: I didn't do it before ... Later on, I used armature bone as driver and it worked ... thank you very much!!!